# NET Core 2 MVC - Storing objects for GET method

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a search form on my index page to search for available rooms and hotels inside an external database. Once the form is submitted, user is redirected to a new page with a list of available hotels (rooms will come later).

After the form is submitted, the search parameters are put into a single string, which is then passed to a TcpConnectionManager class via ModelManager, where this string is serialized to json and sent via socket to an external Java server. The server deserializes the json, places the string elements inside a SQL query, which in turn checks the database and returns all available hotels objects. These hotel objects are then placed in a HotelList object, serialized to json and sent back via socket back to TcpConnectionManager class.

My biggest problem was implementing the GET method inside the HotelController. Tried to store the HotelList object inside the TcpConnectionManager class, but GET method always returned a null object.

So far I have been able to accomplish what I want by implementing a singleton class TempHotelsStorage, which has methods to store and retrieve the HotelList object, but my biggest concern is whether this is a good/right approach in this situation? If not, how can this be improved then?

HomeController.cs :

```
namespace NETCoreWebApp.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IModelManager iModelManager = new ModelManager();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Hotel()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(SearchRoomsModel model)
    {
        string query = string.Format("{0},{1} 12:00,{2} 12:00,{3},{4}", model.Location, model.CheckIn, model.CheckOut, model.NumAdults, model.NumChild);

        iModelManager.GetAvailableRooms(query);

        return RedirectToAction("Hotel");
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
}
```

HotelController.cs:

```
namespace NETCoreWebApp.Controllers
{
[Route("api/hotel")]
[ApiController]
public class HotelController : Controller
{
    public TempHotelsStorage hotelsStorage = TempHotelsStorage.Instance;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<HotelList> Get()
    {            
        return hotelsStorage.GetHotelsFromStorage(); 
    }
}
}
```

TcpConnectionManager.cs :

```
public class TcpConnectionManager
{
    public TempHotelsStorage hotelStorage = TempHotelsStorage.Instance;

    public void GetAvailableRooms(string query)
    {
        //Sending json to other server

        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();

        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6767);

        NetworkStream ns = clientSocket.GetStream();

        string jsonRequest = query;

        string jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonRequest);

        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonToSend);

        ns.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);

        //Receiving json from other server

        byte[] buffer = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

        int bytesRead = ns.Read(buffer, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

        string DataReceived = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 2, bytesRead);

        HotelList hotelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelList>(DataReceived);

        hotelStorage.SaveHotels(hotelList);

        clientSocket.Close();
        ns.Close();
    }
}
```

TempHotelsStorage.cs :

```
namespace NETCoreWebApp.Models
{
public class TempHotelsStorage
{
    private static readonly TempHotelsStorage instance = new TempHotelsStorage();

    static TempHotelsStorage() { }
    private TempHotelsStorage() { }

    public HotelList hotelList { get; set; } = new HotelList();

    public void SaveHotels(HotelList hList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hList.Size(); i++)
        {
            hotelList.AddHotel(hList.GetHotelByIndex(i));
        }
    }

    public HotelList GetHotelsFromStorage()
    {
        return hotelList;
    }

    public static TempHotelsStorage Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
}
```

jQuery to list all hotels:

```
function getData() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: uri,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        const hotelListContainer = $('#hotelListContainer');          

        for (var i = 0; i < data.hotelList.length; i++)
        {
            hotelListContainer
                .append(
                    "<div class='col-md-12' id='hotelListItem'>" +
                    "<div class='col-md-3' id='hotelItemPicture'>ID:" + data.hotelList[i].hid + "</div>" +
                    "<div class='col-md-9' id='hotelItemDescription'>NAME:" + data.hotelList[i].name + "</div>" +
                    "</div>"
                );
        }
    }
});
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="hotelListArea">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8" id="centerHotelListArea">            
        <div id="hotelListContainer">
            <div id="hotelContainerItem"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With your approach result of the search (page with list of available hotels) will return all hotels, which were loaded during application lifetime.

Comment: @Fabio Not sure if I understood what you meant. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: `hotelList` of `TempHotelsStorage` will contain all hotels which were found by different users during application lifetime, because `TempHotelsStorage` is singleton. Your application can run out of memory if users search for the hotels very often.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for the clarification. Any suggestions on how this could be done better?

Comment: Why you can not make `TcpConnectionManager.GetAvailableRooms` return found hotels and then pass it to the view which display search results?

Comment: @Fabio Method GetAvailableRooms() returns the HotelList object to the Home controller POST method, how can I pass this object to the Hotel controllers GET method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save yourself some headache and allow dependency injection to handle the lifespan of your services. You can register a service in `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class by declaring its interface and implementation such as:
`services.AddTransient<ITcpConnectionManager, TcpConnectionManager>();`
Then just add said service as a construtor parameter for your controller.
Also your `TempHotelsStorage` class seems somewhat redundant here. You could avoid using it entirely if you would just `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelList>(DataReceived);` in your `GetAvailableRooms` method. 
In general I would also advise against managing connection and retrieving data in the same method, but that might bet beyond the point of this particular question.

Regarding using singleton objects - you would usually use them in cases where you need to persist an object throughout the lifetime of your application, for example to persist some state. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Following Marchyello advise, using dependency injection I first registered the singleton service in the Startup class:

```
services.AddSingleton<IModelManager, ModelManager>();
```

And then added the singleton service as a constructor parameter for each controller like this:

```
    private readonly IModelManager _modelManager;

    public HotelController(IModelManager modelManager)
    {
        _modelManager = modelManager;
    }
```

ModelManager class, which is simply a facade to the model, acts as a point of access for the api controllers to store and retrieve data by calling GET and POST methods.

HomeController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(SearchRoomsModel model)
    {
        string _query = string.Format("{0},{1} 12:00,{2} 12:00,{3},{4}", model.Location, model.CheckIn, model.CheckOut, model.NumAdults, model.NumChild);

        _modelManager.SaveQuery(_query);

        return RedirectToAction("Hotel");
    }
```

HotelController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<HotelList> Get()
    {
        return _modelManager.ReturnQuery();
    }
```

ModelManager:

```
    private readonly TcpConnectionManager _tcpManager = new TcpConnectionManager();
    public string _query;

    public void SaveQuery(string query)
    {
        _query = query;
    }

    public HotelList ReturnQuery()
    {
        HotelList hotelList = _tcpManager.ReturnHotelList(_query);

        return hotelList;
    }
```

The ModelManager is a singleton because Hotel controller needs to access the same instance of ModelManager that the Home controller has stored the query string to before redirecting to Hotel view. Furthermore, the next step will be to list available rooms based on the hotel selection, and the Room controllers' GET method will need an access to the same HotelList object as the Hotel controller has.